# Issue interacting with QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, shell, stdin, qprocess

I am using QProcesses to run shell commands within a c++ application. One of those commands is an `apt-get install` command. I have the `readyread` signal connected to a method that reads from the process and appends it to a text area on the UI.

My issue is that when the `apt-get install` command starts to run, the line that normally asks "Do you want to continue? [Y/n]" never appears. The last line that gets read by my read line function is the prior line. The QProcess doesn't finish, implying that it is waiting for input.

Why does my `QProcess` wait for input without printing the prompt? How can I handle this case? I have tried using `QProcess::write` to write "Y" to it but it has had no effect.

Sample Code:

```
installPackage = new QProcess(this);
QString programStr = "sudo apt-get -f install";
installPackage->setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);

connect(installPackage, &QProcess::readyRead,this, &MainWindow::readline);

connect(installPackage, static_cast<void(QProcess::*)(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)>(&QProcess::finished),
    [=](){
    MessageBox->append("\n\nOperation Complete.");
});

installPackage->start(programStr);




void readline(){
    while(installPackage->canReadLine()){
        QString line = installPackage->readLine();
        MessageBox->append(line);
        if(line.contains("[Y/n]")) //never evaluates true
            installPackage->write("Y");
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I used the -y option to cause apt-get to automatically answer 'yes' to prompts, but I would still like to know why the prompt didn't happen

Comment: My suspicion is that because the child process is not connected to a tty or pty, it's using full-buffering on its stdout stream rather than line-buffering, which means that a given line is not sent to stdout (and thus to your process) until after its newline is encountered.  If the "Do you want to continue? [Y/n]" prompt doesn't generate a newline (i.e. cursor waits at the end of that line instead of the next line) then it won't get sent, and you're deadlocked.  In my programs I deal with this by having the child process call setlinebuf(stdout); dunno if that is possible with QProcess though.

Comment: @Cobalt: You are using **sudo** though, so it may simply be stuck waiting for a password to be typed in...

Comment: What shell you planning for? embedded shell is one option, interactive shell is the other?

Comment: Using the -y option and reading the std err yielded some info that seems to support @JeremyFriesner 's theory: `debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin`

Comment: It seems as though I need to set an environment variable to make the process non interactive

Answer (score 0):

You have written `readLine()`, but the line hasn't ended yet. It can be noticed by just looking where the cursor is when running `apt-get install`: it's not on the next line but just near the [Y/n].

The `cat` command can show the line endings: `apt-get install brasero | cat -E`.

So `cat` manages to read it fine. It's should be possible to read that text with some kind of block read mode like `read()`.